# WordPress shortcode for output form

Tags: wordpress

I wanna create a form with a shortcode so I can use it wherever I need it. I use the below minimal example:

```
add_shortcode( 'form', 'create_form' );
function create_form () {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/form.php';
}
```

But when I add the shortcode on the post and try to save it, it shows an error: ‘**Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response**.’

I have also noticed that WordPress specifies this:

> shortcode should never produce an output of any kind

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/

There are tons of plugins using the shortcode and outputting something especially some of them are very popular plugins. So they are all doing wrong?

If the shortcode is not meant for making such a task, how do I make a form and add it somewhere? Or the shortcode is okay but I misunderstood and doing something wrong?

Update: The `form.php` is very simple and looks like this:

```
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<label for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
```

Comment: Possibly a misunderstanding. The next sentence of the documentation you quoted says: _Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode_. So, the *add_shortcode()* callback function should not _echo_ but should **return**. Your _create_form()_ code should not _echo_ or _print_ anything. It should instead **return** the HTML (or whatever).

Comment: @kofeigen That's a really great interpretation. But as you can see in the example, I neither 'echo' nor 'return' but I use `require_once` to include the HTML. I have updated the question to show the `form.php`. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says to **return** something. But, the create_form() function does not return anything. The content of form.php should be **return**-ed as a string rather than only *require*-ed.

For example:

```php
add_shortcode( 'form', 'create_form' );
function create_form () {
    $form_filepath = __DIR__ . '/form.php';
    $form_html = file_get_contents( $form_filepath );
    return $form_html;
}
```